# System.NullPointerException while calling extends System.WebServiceCalloutFuture in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Apex Test Class :

```
Test.startTest();
        BBService.WSDocLitInterfaceDoc_elementFuture elem = new BBService.WSDocLitInterfaceDoc_elementFuture();
        BBService.CO_INCIDENT_element getValue = elem.getValue();

Test.stopTest();
```

Apex class :

```
public class BBService {
public class WSDocLitInterfaceDoc_elementFuture extends System.WebServiceCalloutFuture {
    public SMBBService.CO_INCIDENT_element getValue() {
       BBService.WSDocLitInterfaceDoc_element response = (BBService.WSDocLitInterfaceDoc_element)System.WebServiceCallout.endInvoke(this);
        return response.CO_INCIDENT;
    }
}
```

return null exception

Comment: Did you set mockTest for soap API?

Comment: Refer [Test Web Service Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm)